# Unsubs Tracking Extract from new Child BU not populated

Tags: marketing-cloud

I created a new BU in our SFMC instance for dev purposes. I built an automation to pull daily unsub extracts from all BUs (there's the Parent BU and 2 additional child BUs) and I'm running the automation in the new Dev BU.

Automation runs successfully without errors but the extract is an empty file.

Running the same automation in the Parent BU has records populated in the extract.

Is it only possible to pull extracts from the parent BU?